# Go User Login Using GIn-Gonic

Tags: go

I'm having a bit of trouble in logging in using gin-gonic in making a web application. I'm currently using an API for it. where I can make requests for entry. This is my code snippets:

**main**

```
// LOGIN
router.GET("/login", loginUser)
router.POST("/login", login)
```

**snippet for login function**

```
// LOGIN FUNCTIONS

func loginUser(c *gin.Context) {
c.HTML(200, "login.html", gin.H{})

}

func login(c *gin.Context) {


email := c.PostForm("email")
password := c.PostForm("password")



r := gin.Default()
r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
r.POST("/api/user/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
    var json common.Login
    if err := common.Bind(c, &json); err == nil {

        if json.Email == email && json.Password == password {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{"email":email, "password": password,})
            fmt.Println(email)
            fmt.Println(password)       

        } else {
            c.JSON(401, common.NewError("user", errors.New("wrong username or password")))
            c.HTML(404, "404notification.html", gin.H{})

        }
        c.HTML(200, "notification.html", gin.H{"email": email})

    } else {
        c.JSON(422, common.NewValidatorError(err))
    }
})
r.Run()




}
```

As you can see im trying to post request my credentials in order to login.

When I click submit on my form box in function `loginUser`-  **login** recieves the post request and then redirects itself to the html when success and the 404error html if wrong.

I dont know if my understanding is right, it's my second day learning this to make web apps. Help pls

Answer (score 0):

you use file extension (.html). if you want to use master page or not?

if you want to use master page then you not write any extension for example "home/index".

if you want to use not master page then you write full path "home/index.html"